# Unsure what a special variable means in Proc SQL in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.sasanalysis.com/2011/01/top-10-most-powerful-functions-for-proc.html) for sas proc sql. I don't understand the role of the `ss11`. variable in the line

```
format ssn1 ssn2 ssn11.;
```

Full code

```
data ssn_data;
  do i = 1 to 1000;
  ssn1 = ceil((ranuni(1234)*1E9));
  ssn2 = ssn1;
  if ssn1 le ceil((ranuni(1000)*1E9)) then call missing(ssn1);
  if ssn2 le ceil((rannor(2000)*1E9)) then call missing(ssn2);
  drop i;
  output;
end;
format ssn1 ssn2 ssn11.;
run;
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a default [format](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59498.pdf) in SAS for Social Security numbers. In the above code, `SSN11.` applies format to both `ssn1` & `ssn2` variables.

Here's an example,

```
data test;
Input name$ ssn_number;
Datalines;
Teena 123456789
Rahul 002124444
;
run;
```

Applying format (Since your tutorial relates to `Proc SQL`)

```
proc sql ;
select name, ssn_number format=ssn11.
from test;
quit;
```

Creates below output,

```
Name ssn_number
----------
Teena 123-45-6789
Rahul 002-12-4444
```

Comment: Added a link to the SAS doc that explains what formats are, since that is probably part of the issue here.